# Why did a moderator delete this seemingly legitimate answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-answers

I was searching for code help, and came to this question: [kill another process/application programmatically [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9563404/996493). This question has one proper [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875490/996493) that has been deleted by moderator.

Following is a screenshot of the deleted answer:

> [image: screenshot of deleted answer]

What could be the reason to delete such an answer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After digging a little, I was able to figure out that the answer was deleted because the user posted exact copies of the answer to a plethora of different questions. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-in-android/18875656#18875656) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588893/not-able-to-kill-running-application/18875585#18875585) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254199/how-to-force-stop-the-application-programatically-android/18875564#18875564) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196082/force-stop-the-application-programatically-android/18875523#18875523) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563404/kill-another-process-application-programmatically/18875490#18875490)

Since you claim that the answer is helpful for that question, I'll leave that one undeleted since I already undeleted it. But at least you have some sort of explanation.

Comment: I thought about this part but was not able to find other posts of the user that's why I asked this question.

Comment: If a moderator leaves a comment (like "please don't post the exact same answer to 5 questions") on a post like this, will it stick around after the deletion to explain to passersby later why the answer was deleted? And is that what should happen?

Comment: @Kate Comments stick around, yes. But we don't usually post one on *every* answer.

Comment: But if the comment is on the deleted answer, only passersby with enough rep to see deleted answers would be able to see the comment.